# VueJS multiple nested route not rendering by router-view

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this set up in my Vue components,

My problem is, its not rendering the component Goal.vue when I'm trying to change to its route unless I refreshed the page. I already did the setting up 
the `:key` and also `$forceUpdate`. However, its working when I route to it self like `this.$router.go(0);` but its a bit ugly because its like rendering the page twice.

**Evaluation.vue**

```
  <keep-alive>
      <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
  </keep-alive>
```

**Dashboard.vue**

```
    <keep-alive>
      <router-view :key="$route.fullPath" v-cloak></router-view>
    </keep-alive>
```

And Goal.vue

Its like

```
+--------------------+
| Evaluation         |
| +----------------+ |
| | Dashboard      | |
| | +------------+ | |
| | |            | | |
| | |            | | |
| | |    Goal    | | |
| | |            | | |
| | +------------+ | |
| +----------------+ |
+--------------------+
```

And here is my route

```
const ev = {
  name: "evaluate_employee",
  path: "evaluate_employee/:emp_eval_id?",
  exact: true,
  component: Evaluation,
  meta: {
    prefix: 'Evaluate Employee',
    icon: 'person',
    title: 'Evaluation - ',
    permissions: ["auth"],
    requiresAuth: false
  },
  children:[
    {
      name:'evaluating',
      path:'evaluating/:eval_id?',
      exact: true,
      component: Dashboard,
      meta: {
        prefix: 'Evaluating User - ',
        icon: '',
        title: 'Evaluating - ',
        permission:['auth'],
        requiresAuth: false
      },
      children:[
        {
          name: 'eval_goal',
          path: '', // evaluating/:eval_id?/
          exact: true,
          component: Goal,
          meta: {
            prefix: 'Performance Assessment - ',
            icon: '',
            title: 'Performance Assessment - ',
            permission: ['auth'],
            requiresAuth: false
          },
        },

      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Would you like to provide a JSfiddle or CodePen ?